# Issue with sending email in python

Tags: python

Below is the code which works perfectly fine if placed in main script. Send ana email to recipient in outlook

```
import smtplib
import base64

filename = "/tmp/test.txt"

# Read a file and encode it into base64 format
fo = open(filename, "rb")
filecontent = fo.read()
encodedcontent = base64.b64encode(filecontent)  # base64

sender = 'webmaster@tutorialpoint.com'
reciever = 'amrood.admin@gmail.com'

marker = "AUNIQUEMARKER"

body ="""
This is a test email to send an attachement.
"""
# Define the main headers.
part1 = """From: From Person <me@fromdomain.net>
To: To Person <amrood.admin@gmail.com>
Subject: Sending Attachement
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=%s
--%s
""" % (marker, marker)

# Define the message action
part2 = """Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit

%s
--%s
""" % (body,marker)

# Define the attachment section
part3 = """Content-Type: multipart/mixed; name=\"%s\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s

%s
--%s--
""" %(filename, filename, encodedcontent, marker)
message = part1 + part2 + part3

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, reciever, message)
   print "Successfully sent email"
except Exception:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

BUt when I call it in funtion

```
filename = "/tmp/test.txt"
def send_email(filename):

    # Read a file and encode it into base64 format
    fo = open(filename, "rb")
    filecontent = fo.read()
    encodedcontent = base64.b64encode(filecontent)  # base64

    sender = 'webmaster@tutorialpoint.com'
    reciever = 'amrood.admin@gmail.com'

    marker = "AUNIQUEMARKER"

    body ="""
    This is a test email to send an attachement.
    """
    # Define the main headers.
    part1 = """From: From Person <me@fromdomain.net>
    To: To Person <amrood.admin@gmail.com>
    Subject: Sending Attachement
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=%s
    --%s
    """ % (marker, marker)

    # Define the message action
    part2 = """Content-Type: text/plain
    Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit

    %s
    --%s
    """ % (body,marker)

    # Define the attachment section
    part3 = """Content-Type: multipart/mixed; name=\"%s\"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s

    %s
    --%s--
    """ %(filename, filename, encodedcontent, marker)
    message = part1 + part2 + part3

    try:
       smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
       smtpObj.sendmail(sender, reciever, message)
       print "Successfully sent email"
    except Exception:
       print "Error: unable to send email"
```

It send an email with blank sender, recipient and message. The previous code  sends an email with an attachment perfectly fine. I believe I am doing silly mistake in defining the variables but cant make out.

Not sure what am I doing wrong.
Can you please help